# Why is props sent from parent component become object in child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I'am implementing a language translation system for my React app and I'm stuck on displaying the languages flags as Modal when the user click on the tranlation icon, which should display the list of languages to tranlate to. I have a LanguageModal.jsx child component which is a Modal triggered from NavigationBar.jsx parent component. These are the two components:

```
// Languagemodal.jsx
import React from 'react';
import './languageModal.css';
import en from '../../assets/flags/US.png';
import de from '../../assets/flags/DE.png';
import fr from '../../assets/flags/FR.png';

const languageModal = (show) => (show
  ? (
    <div className="Modal">
      <div className="Modal-content">
        <div className="Modal-body">
          <div><img src={en} alt="english" /></div>
          <div><img src={de} alt="deutsch" /></div>
          <div><img src={fr} alt="francais" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (null));
export default languageModal;

// NavigationBar.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { FaGlobe } from 'react-icons/fa';
import logo from '../../assets/logodidi.png';
import Modal from '../LanguageModal/languageModal.jsx';
import './navigationBar.css';

const NavigationBar = () => {
  const [toggleBar, setToggleBar] = useState(false);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setShow(show);
  }, [show]);
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div id="max-width">
        <div className="navbar-items">
          <div className="navbar-items_container">
            <p><a href="#home">home</a></p>
            <p><a href="#usage">Usage</a></p>
            <p><a href="#Categories">Categories</a></p>
            <p><a href="#Blogs">Blogs</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="navbar-sign">
          <p><FaGlobe color="#2b74b7" onClick={() => (setShow(true))} /></p>
          <languageModal show={show} />
          <button type="button">Get started</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavigationBar;
```

The expected behavior is to display  only when the user cliks on the **FaGlob icon**. The problem is that the Modal is automatically displayed without a click. so I set the variable "show" with React hook useState and useEffect to manage show/hide the Modal but not to avail, the Modal is always being displayed anyway. When I check the "show" value with docuemnt.write(show) I saw that it is "false" in the parent component but it gives [object object] in the languageModal child component. When I change the "show" initial value it doesn't take any effect inside the child languageModal component unless I manualy change it inside it by changing the

```
const languageModal = (show) => (show
  ? ( ... )
```

to

```
const languageModal = (show) => (!show
  ? (...)
```

And that is the weird point. Why the child component doesn't receive the value passed to it? Where is it taking the default value [object object] from, since "show" isn't an object but a boolean ? How to solve it then. Your help is very appreciated. I can't go forth whithout your help.

Comment: `const languageModal = (show) =>` what you've called "show" is the entire props object. Did you mean to do `const languageModal = ({ show }) =>`?

Comment: @Nicholas Tower Thanks you are right. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `show` like that, `show` will be `props`. That is why it is an object. If you want to extract a particular property, you can either do `props.show` or use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the functional component like this `{show}`

```
const languageModal = ({show}) => (show
  ? (
    <div className="Modal">
      <div className="Modal-content">
        <div className="Modal-body">
          <div><img src={en} alt="english" /></div>
          <div><img src={de} alt="deutsch" /></div>
          <div><img src={fr} alt="francais" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (null));
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sens why I got object and Indeed I received such alert about "destructuring show" but don't understand what it does. My googleed about "destructuring props" but were even moreconfusing because it was asking to use backtips like '${show}'. What does it mean destructuring ? I Would like to understand.

Comment: I have edited the answer with the one link you should look at. I think you reached some wrong page, which might be explaining something else.

Answer (score 1):

You are destructuring `show` incorrectly. Update it as:

```
const languageModal = ({show}) => (show
  ? (
    <div className="Modal">
      <div className="Modal-content">
        <div className="Modal-body">
          <div><img src={en} alt="english" /></div>
          <div><img src={de} alt="deutsch" /></div>
          <div><img src={fr} alt="francais" /></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (null));
export default languageModal;
```

Comment: Yeah thanks @NeERAJ TK. indeed I was receiving such alert about "destructuring show" but I dont really understand what it does. My searchs about it on google were confusing because I was changinging it using backtips like '${how}'. What does it mean destructuring ? I Would like to understand.

Comment: @Prenam Refer [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component/) .

Comment: Yeah thanks @NeERAJ TK.